# Existe uma Tag no Django para mostrar parte do texto?

Tags: python, django

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma tag para mostrar parte de uma descrição

```
{{ post.description | tag-aqui }}
```

Comment: Com "uma parte" você quer dizer limitar o número de caracteres?

Comment: Sim, limitar o numero para que a descrição completa seja vista quando detalhar o poste.

Answer (score 1):

Como a intenção é apenas limitar o número de caracteres, basta utilizar o filtro `slice`:

```
{{ post.description | slice:"0:255" }}
```

Desta forma, serão exibidos os caracteres nas posições entre 0 e 255.

[**Documentação oficial**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)